# Why doesn't Spark establish JDBC driver dependency even though the JAR's were submitted?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I am trying to submit jdbc jar's to Spark shell for an initial analysis before submitting the spark job to a cluster.
 This is what I am doing - in windows -

```
 C:\spark>spark-shell --driver-class-path C:\tera\terajdbc4.jar,C:\tera\tdgssconfig.jar --jars C:\tera\terajdbc4.jar,C:\tera\tdgssconfig.jar
```

Looking at the Spark Docs (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) - this should work.

But when I try

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:teradata://xxxxx/TMODE=TERA").option("dbtable", "dummy").option("user", "xxxx").option("password", "xxxx").load()
```

I get this

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$7.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$7.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:84)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:83)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:34)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:34)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
  ... 48 elided
```

If anyone can tell me the right way that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the JDBC url - 
val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").**option("driver","com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")**.option("url", "jdbc:teradata:///TMODE=TERA/CHARSET=UTF16/DATABASE=").option("dbtable", "**table**").option("user", "**username**").option("password", "**password**").load()

This did the trick.